# Configure Control-m job using in condition

Tags: control-m

[Control-m Job description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uu4uz.png)

Job A runs Mon-Friday, Job B runs on Saturday. Job C runs Mon-Saturday. I need Job D to run when: 
1)Job A and Job C runs or 
2) Job B and Job C runs.

Is this possible using control-m, how should I modify the in-condition.

Answer (score 0):

I would modify so that Job A and Job B pass the same condition.  Job D will be waiting on condition from Job A or Job B, and from Job C.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to this is to make use of an OR when defining the in-conditions on Job D.

Solution:
Job A, Job B and Job C all post normal out-conditions to Job D.
Job D is configured to require the following in-conditions
(Job A AND (Job B OR Job C))